# magnific popup custom on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

to trigger magnific popup

```
<a href="#role_popup" data-effect="mfp-zoom-in" class="xx open-popup-link">Click</a>
<a href="#role_popup" data-effect="mfp-zoom-in" class="xx open-popup-link">Click</a>
<a href="#role_popup" data-effect="mfp-zoom-in" class="xx open-popup-link">Click</a>
```

I successfully open a magnific popup however I have this custom click function with a link associated with the magnific popup .

```
$(".xx").click(function(e){
    alert("test");
});
```

and I have multiple magnific popup link and I want to show alert popup when I click each of them but sadly it only alert once. Any help, suggestions, recommendations, clues, ideas is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There must be something else going on as on it's own you can see it works multiple times.  Please expand this fiddle to help us debug for you.  http://jsfiddle.net/kca40fmw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

```
$(document).on("click", ".xx", function(){
    //do something here
});
```